Connection of Protective Earth for EV charging
I am reading about the EV charging at J1772, where a connector image is displayed. The connector has a PE terminal. I read that the Protective Earth is connected to a earth rod on the charging station side.

So, this earth rod will be connected to the metal case of the charging box also, right?

On the vehicle side, where does this Protective Earth get connected to?

Will this protective earth be connected to the Chassis of the car?

Is the purpose of this PE just similar to the Earth for other general electrical appliances?




At last in North America, that diagram is wrong. Here, the PE wire goes back to the electrical panel, like any other grounded appliance. Back at the panel, PE connects to ground rod(s) as well as being bonded to neutral. (Actually there may happen at different panels, if a detached out building is involved.)

@DoxyLover, Ok, In that case in North America, the PE wire will be connected to the metal casing of the charging equipment? Also, will the PE wire be connected to the chassis of the car?

I take it you're in the UK?

@ThreePhaseEel, yes in the UK

The UK is a big hot mess when it comes to EV charging.  This is because of decisions made decades ago, to scrimp on wires in the street. John Ward's excellent video covers the underlying issue well.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE
Since PE can be dangerous, the safety of Britons haa mainly relied upon "earthed" electrical equipment rarely being near any actual earth.  Caravan parking spaces and boat docks require a special approach not feasible at every home.  So UK regulators really painted themselves into a corner for EV charging.
The answer is a complex set of regulations for how exactly to connect an EV station. It practically fills a book lol.
John Ward's has another video on that topic alone, here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZVx7GbAwlg. That or the algorithm-recommended videos below will tell you a lot.
It typically involves EVSEs or external boxes which detect PEN faults and interrupt all wires including earth (!), or elaborate earthing mesh laid or cast under the parking spot, as a mere spike is not enough.  As discussed in the top video, RCD/GFCI is about as useful as a chocolate teapot.
I know you want it to be easy, but it's not.
